# How to make Google Maps Navigation show forward as up?

Tags: google-maps-navigation

It used to be that Google Maps Navigation on my phone would show the direction of travel = as "up" on the screen. However, ever since my phone upgraded to Gingerbread, navigation is displayed with North as "up" on the screen.

How do I revert to the old behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that the solution to this is rather easy, but scarcely documented.

To switch between forward-is-up and north-is-up, simply tap the red/white compass needle in the upper left hand corner of the screen.

On the updated maps, where the red/white compass icon is no longer there, goto settings and turn off "North is always up'

Comment: tapping on it did not change anything. It still points to north. Any ideas how to get it back to the direction of travel orientation. It started when offline maps were downloaded an used.

Comment: As of 7/2019 it's in "Navigation Settings" near the bottom.  "Keep map north up"